# Pandas Drop and Replace functions won't work within a UDF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I looked around at other questions but couldn't find out that addresses the issue I'm having. I am cleaning a data set in an ipython notebook. When I run the cleaning tasks individually they work as expected, but I am having trouble with the replace() and drop() functions when they are included in a UDF. Specifically, these lines aren't doing anything within the UDF, however, a dataframe is returned that completes the other tasks as expected (i.e. reads in the file, sets the index, and filters select dates out).

Any help is much appreciated!

Note that in this problem the df.drop() and df.replace() commands both work as expected when executed outside of the UDF. The function is below for your reference. The issue is with the last two lines "station.replace()" and "station.drop()".

```
def read_file(file_path):
    '''Function to read in daily x data'''
    if os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+'/'+file_path) == True:
        station = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    else:
        !unzip alldata.zip
        station = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    station.set_index('date',inplace=True) #put date in the index
    station = station_data[station_data.index > '1984-09-29'] #removes days where there is no y-data
    station.replace('---','0',inplace=True)
    station.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1,inplace=True) #drop non-station columns
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake here:

```
station = station_data[station_data.index > '1984-09-29']
```

I was using an old table index. I corrected it to:

```
station = station[station.index > '1984-09-29']
```

Note, I had to restart the notebook and re-run it from the top for it to work. I believe it was an issue with conflicting table names in the UDF vs. what was already stored in memory.